# What does %c character formatting do in Python and it's use?

Tags: python, string

Going through string formatting operations but can't exactly wrap my head about %c operation and its use.

Learn Python the Hard Way, gave the following example but it makes little sense without the proper context.

```
"%c" % 34 == '"'
```

Here is the link to if anyone wants to check it out:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex37.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives the character that is represented by the ASCII code "34".

If you look up an ASCII table you will notice that 34 = "

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` is a [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) gives the character representation. For example consider the following statements

```
>>> print "%c" % 'a'
a
>>> print ("%c" % 97)
a
>>> print "%c" %'"'
"
>>> print "%c" %34
"
>>> print "%c" %'asdf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %c requires int or char
```

---

Breaking up

```
"%c" % 34 == '"'
```

would be like

```
>>> "%c" % 34
"
>> '"' == '"'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

[`%c` represents character values.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)  It's part of the integer representation types.

You can't enter a value larger than an unsigned byte (255) as a positional argument to it, so be careful where and when you elect to use it.